# Using HTTP as a transport layer between client/server applications

Tags: .net, http, rest

I would like to expose some data to client applications via HTTP.  For example, the client would go to URL: http://mysite.com/books/12345 to obtain data about book 12345.  The client could do an HTTP PUT or POST to http://mysite.com/books/54321 to upload data about book 54321.  Is this known as a RESTful web service?

I have no idea where to start though.  I would like to write the server logic in C#/.NET keeping in mind the clients will be using non-Microsoft technologies such as C++, Objective-C, and Java, so I don't want to get locked into something that only works in the Microsoft .NET environment.  The clients will also be running over cellular connections with limited bandwidth.  I would like to use a compact and portable protocol over HTTP like Google Protocol Buffers to allow communications between different languages and platforms.

Which Microsoft technology should I use to write a RESTful web service like I described in my first paragraph?  Which open source technology could I use to write the RESTful web service described in the first paragraph?  Does it matter which web server I use?  Is it OK to send binary data (protobuf) over a HTTP connection?   How would I push new data out to a client from the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use WCF, more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/cc950529.aspx).  There is even a WCF REST starter kit to get you going.